# Nexus repository manager gives 401 unathorized error on dependency packages

Tags: npm, nexus, yarn-v2

I use a private repository on nexus, and in most cases it works on my project, I am able to download the packages, but on some packages , which is already there it throws 401:

```
verbose 0.888516971 Performing "GET" request to "http://nexus.xxxxx.click/repository/xxxx-group/@types%2fscheduler".
verbose 0.889184174 Performing "GET" request to "http://nexus.xxxxx.click/repository/xxxx-group/csstype".
verbose 0.95447878 Request "http://nexus.xxxxx.click/repository/xxxx-group/@types%2fprop-types" finished with status code 200.
verbose 1.060270698 Request "http://nexus.xxxxx.click/repository/xxxx-group/csstype" finished with status code 401.
```

NPM Bearer token realm is Active. The repository is same for all packages, and I am able to see the csstype in the browser properly.
Tried to fetch either with npm and yarn too, always 401 on some packages. I checked the privileges and roles on them, same for all package.

- yarn version : 1.22.19
- node version : v18.7.0
- npm version : 8.15.0

Any ideas?

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I'm facing the same issue here for days...